# Redirect http to https using docker-compose

Tags: docker, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I'm having a jenkins container running on my gcp instance and want to redirect to https when someone enters a url with http extension.

Here my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
jenkins:
  image: jenkins/jenkins
  container_name: jenkins-docker
  restart: always
  privileged: true
  user: root
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:8443
    - 50000:50000
  volumes:
    - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    - ../opt/cert/dcsjenkins.jks:/var/lib/jenkins/dcsjenkins.jks
  environment:
    JAVA_OPTS: -Duser.timezone=CET -Xmx2048m -Djava.awt.headless=true
    JENKINS_OPTS: --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443
```

Comment: With above configuration, this container is not accessible through http. It only accessible through https. What my requirement is , when someone enter the url with http it should redirect to this jenkins container with https

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

Try setting the `--httpsRedirectHttp` flag on server startup. It requires both `HTTP` and `HTTPs` ports defined.

```
--httpsRedirectHttp = redirect http requests to https (requires both --httpPort and --httpsPort)
```

All available flags can be found [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/winstone/blob/master/README.md#command-line-options).

#### Solution 2

The other option is to deploy a reverse proxy before the Jenkins container. If you are already using an LB in GCP to expose your Jenkins instance, you can simply add a rule there to redirect HTTP traffic.